# Number of values represented on a connect 4 board

Tags: combinatorics

How many game states are there for a valid non-ended game of connect $4$?

Context + my thoughts: It's a $7 \times 6$ board with three values for each location: red, blue, or blank.

We can't just use a ternary (three-value) system similar to binary (would be $3^{7\times 6}$, I think?) because there's many non-valid game states. There can't be any reds or blues that are four-in-a-row, and any blank locations cannot have a red or blue location directly above them (or the red/blue would fall down). I'm working under the assumption that there are any number of red and blue pieces.

Here's [the wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connect_Four) of the game for anyone who is unfamiliar with it.

Apologies if I haven't added the right tag, I'm new to stackexchange.

Comment: Another constraint is that the number of red and blue locations can't differ by more than $1$ (since the players take turns).

Comment: This is quite an involved question and is likely more difficult than you think.  This is research paper level difficulty.  According to [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A212693) Edelkamp and Kissmann showed that there are $4,531,985,219,092\approx 4.5\cdot 10^{12}$ valid board positions.  See [the paper by Edelkamp and Kissmann](http://www.tzi.de/~edelkamp/publications/conf/ki/EdelkampK08-1.pdf) which I would have thought goes into detail on how this was calculated (*upon reading it it seems OEIS might be referring to a different paper*).  [See also](http://tromp.github.io/c4/c4.html).

Comment: @JMoravitz, note, the OP is asking about the number of *non-ended* game states, whle the OEIS entry (and references) appear to count ended game states as well. Also, the OEIS entry, which begins $1, 7, 49$, seems to assume one color (say red) goes first, while the OP's wiki page link implies either color can go first, in which case the ply sequence starts $1,14,56$.  (If you come upon an unfinished game, you can always tell which color's turn is next if there's an odd number of discs in play, but only sometimes if there's an even number.)